# Under voltage lockout circuit design

Tags: buck-boost, undervoltage

I need to be able to switch a load circuit off when the output voltage from a buck boost converter is around 3V (or below 4V or 5V).

The converter is powered by a 10W solar panel and the load can draw a max of around 560mA. The converter is set to 12V output, but whenever the panel is in shade and then put in sunlight, the converter doesn't have time to properly switch on because the rest of the circuit is drawing all available current (I understand this is called stall?) at 3V and starts overheating quickly. I then need to disconnect the load for the converter to switch on properly.

I have found a few undervoltage circuits online, but nothing that I can use or adjust. Mainly because I am a newbie when it comes to circuit design. So I can't calculate the values and don't know which mosfets to use.

Any help with part values and advice would be much appreciated. Here are three circuits that look simple enough. If you have any suggestions, that would be great too.

[image]

*Image source: https://www.powerctc.com/.*

[image]

*Image source: http://s3.amazonaws.com.*

[image]

Comment: Use a voltage supervisor IC. The kind for microcontrollers and connect it to the enable input of your converter if it has one. But since you are using a PMOS load switch, I assume you do not have one.

Comment: Most such ICs don't go up to 12V though...you may need to clamp the input with a series resistor and divdier so it doesn't die in full light.

Comment: Thanks, I would rather not mess with the converter though. It also only has a power input and output. I was thinking of clamping the transistors or mosfets with a zener if necessary. I just don't know how to calculate what exact parts to use

Comment: Where did I say anything about messing with the converter?

Comment: I am just saying that I need a stand-alone circuit, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: What makes you think what I am talking about is not a standalone circuit?

Comment: I'm not interested in a pointless argument. If I have not asked my question clearly, then please tell me what information I should add. But I think I made it very clear that I am looking for help regarding the part values to the circuits above or something similar. Thank you for your suggestions so far though

Comment: I don't think there's anything you need to add really. You just keep coming back making comments as though you read something completely different from what I wrote. In none of what I said did I talk about opening up the converter, or having a circuit that was not standalone.